# Conditionally replace values in rows using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm have a data.frame with variables that are indexed by group and year like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(8675309)

df <- data.frame(
  year = rep(1991:2000, 10), 
  groups = rep(1:10, each = 10), 
  var1 = rnorm(100), 
  var2 = rnorm(100)
)

head(df)

  year groups       var1        var2
1 1991      1 -0.9965824  0.74453768
2 1992      1  0.7218241 -1.34662801
3 1993      1 -0.6172088  0.33014251
4 1994      1  2.0293916 -0.01272533
5 1995      1  1.0654161 -0.46367596
6 1996      1  0.9872197  0.20494209
```

where some of the observations are missing for a specific year, say, 1996:

```
df[df$year == 1996, ]$var1 <- ifelse(df[df$year == 1996, ]$var1 > 0,
                                    NA, df[df$year == 1996, ]$var1)
## If 1996 is missing in var1, it is missing in all vars:
df$var2 <- ifelse(is.na(df$var1), NA, df$var2)
```

My question is, how can I replace the values of `var1` and `var2` conditional on whether or not they already exist? This is the gist of what I want:

```
df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(replace_1996_if_NA_with_value_from_1994))
```

Comment: Do you rather mean conditional on wether or not `var1` is positive, for each group?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel no, whether or not `var1` is `NA` when `year==1996`

Comment: Please use `set.seed` when using such functions as `rnorm`

Comment: What would you like to replace the `NA`'s with?

Comment: Note that I updated the data -- in the original, all of 1994 was group 4 (and 91 was group 1, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes this unclear, but if you have some default value that you always want to use to replace a missing value (e.g., if 1994 is your baseline), then I would recommend that you first generate those defaults:

```
defaultValues <-
  df %>%
  filter(year == 1994) %>%
  select(groups
         , default_var1 = var1
         , default_var2 = var2)
```

Then, use `left_join` to merge on the groups. That way, each row will now also have a default. You can then use `coalesce` to pick the first non-NA value -- which will be the default if and only if the value is missing. End by cleaning away the default values.

```
df %>%
  left_join(defaultValues) %>%
  mutate(var1 = coalesce(var1, default_var1)
         , var2 = coalesce(var2, default_var2)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("default"))
```

If your defaults are more complex, you would just need to construct them to match your desired behavior. For example, if you want it to fill in the value from two years prior, use:

```
complex_defaultValues <-
  df %>%
  mutate(year = year + 2) %>%
  rename(default_var1 = var1
         , default_var2 = var2)
```

then, join on both year and group, and it will correctly align (though note that if the value from two years ago are missing, it will still be missing after `coalesce`. So, you may need to account for the missings in your defaults as well.)

Finally, if you just want to propagate the last non-NA value forward (instead of trying to go back two years, or always using the same default), you can use `fill` from `tidyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  fill(var1, var2)
```

Which will automatically fill down (so make sure your data are sorted in the way you want)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's unclear how you'd like to replace missing values, I replace them using mean imputation (taking the mean of the column and using that to replace the value).

```
# Some of the observations are now missing
n <- 10
df[cbind(sample(1:nrow(df), n, replace=T), sample(1:ncol(df), n, replace=T))] <- NA
```

We extract the rows containing `NA`'s

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0,]
#    year groups        var1       var2
# 5  1995      1          NA -0.4636760
# 14 1994      2          NA  1.1556394
# 34 1994     NA  0.58852729 -0.7053416
# 37 1997      4  0.06391704         NA
# 47 1997     NA -0.87493144  1.1691501
# 50 2000      5  0.03609091         NA
# 54 1994     NA -2.13523626 -1.0991012
# 80 2000      8 -1.35752606         NA
# 84   NA      9  0.02038586 -1.6054171
# 92 1992     NA  0.59155773 -1.768570
```

Replace with means using `dplyr`'s `mutate_each()`

```
newDF <- mutate_each(df, funs(ifelse(is.na(.), mean(., na.rm=T), .)))
```

Updated columns:

```
newDF[rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0,]
```

```
       year  groups        var1        var2
# 5  1995.000 1.00000  0.04923291 -0.46367596
# 14 1994.000 2.00000  0.04923291  1.15563940
# 34 1994.000 5.46875  0.58852729 -0.70534164
# 37 1997.000 4.00000  0.06391704 -0.04406217
# 47 1997.000 5.46875 -0.87493144  1.16915008
# 50 2000.000 5.00000  0.03609091 -0.04406217
# 54 1994.000 5.46875 -2.13523626 -1.09910122
# 80 2000.000 8.00000 -1.35752606 -0.04406217
# 84 1995.515 9.00000  0.02038586 -1.60541710
# 92 1992.000 5.46875  0.59155773 -1.76857084
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to replace the missing rows with values from another row (e.g. if all the values for year 1996 in a certain group are missing, replace them with the values for that group in 1994)